# View Base64 encoded pdf on android devices

Tags: android, ios, pdf, cordova, base64

I am working on a cordova project and trying to view base64 encoded pdf file on android devices. I tried using data:application/pdf;base64, and appending base64 encoded string at the end, the file successfully opened up in ios device but not on android device. The issue is coming for pdf only, i am able to open images on both ios and android using data:image/png;base64,.

Please can anyone suggest a solution for android.

Thanks.